# How exactly do healing spells interact with the conditions they remove?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing

Some alternate rules like inflicting scars or fungal grafts can be removed with greater restoration, heal, or any spell that heals HP damage.

[Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft)

> A fungal graft can be removed with a heal or greater restoration spell, or with a successful Heal check against the original DC in another hour-long surgery.

This can be extremely annoying, as most of these require high skill check rolls and over 5,000 GP to create, I can't find any rules for picking out which injuries are and aren't healed (e.g. A man without a finger does not want it restored as it has sentimental value, or a deeper meaning to him, but his other hand gets chopped off in a battle, how do you restore one hand without restoring the finger?).

Does someone who gets injured, but does not want it healed, have to avoid *all* heal and restore spells, simply to avoid wasting resources? It wouldn't make much sense for a spell to discern each injury's intent.

Comment: Um. Couldn't the (seriously hardcore) dude, once his finger's magically regrown, just chop it off again?

Comment: And do they cover congenital effects, anyways?  What about wearing glasses - usually the condition worsens over time...

Comment: Besides fungal grafts and scars, are there other effects that need to be addressed? (An answer is usually better when the question's really specific, so if other effects *are* a concern you should list them, and if there aren't any you can make this question specifically about fungal grafts and scars.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Not really, but I do come across a lot of effects that remove important stuff, this makes it hard for people who have physical deformations on purpose, or evil healers who only do so to keep people alive for torture. -- Removing fingers on purpose does sound like a cheap alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Scars and similar wounds

When using the Combat section's [Optional Rules: Scars and Wounds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat)—half of which is *just* scars—or after having gained scars from another source,<sup>1</sup> unless the scar's source *says* the scar is healed by magic, the scar *isn't* healed by magic. Scars aren't mentioned as removed by the spell [*heal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heal), the spell [*regenerate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/regenerate), any version of the spell [*restoration*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restoration), nor any spell like [*cure light wounds*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds).<sup>2</sup> Note, however, that scars gained *via* the Optional Rules: Scars and Wounds explicitly *are* removed by the spell *regenerate*.

## Grafts and similar items

The Fungal Grafts from the [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) skill's Expanded Alchemy Options says that

> A fungal graft **can be removed** with a *heal* or *greater restoration* spell, or with a successful Heal check against the original DC in another hour-long surgery.

Emphasis mine. In *Pathfinder* *can* typically means *has the capacity to* or *is able to but need not* (hence largely synonymous with *may*; cf. *must*). Thus the section on Fungal Grafts implies that a caster that targets a creature that possesses one or more fungal grafts *picks* whether to remove the target's fungal grafts, much like a creature using the skill Heal could elect *not* to perform surgery.

A creature possessing other organic replacements and additions—such as the [*demon senses*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/demon-senses), the [*demon talon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/demon-talon), the [*glabrezu claw*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/artifacts), the [*sin runes*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/sin-runes), and those created by the feat [Inscribe Magic Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation)—seems to keep those even if the creature's the target of the spell *heal* or *greater restoration*.<sup>3</sup>

## Don't get sentimental: This is only the body you're in *right now*

By the time an adventurer is level 7, his friends should be able to rustle up a [*reincarnate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate) spell for a [dead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Dead) companion, and that spell—the lowest-level spell that brings back a dead creature—brings back the dead creature "in a new body[, as t]he magic of the spell creates an entirely new young adult body for the soul to inhabit from the natural elements at hand." The spell [*raise dead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/raise-dead) requires a dead creature, yet the spells *reincarnate* and [*resurrection*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resurrection) require only a *portion* and [*true resurrection*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-resurrection) but a *name*.

So only for levels 9–12, when adventurers have (possibly) outgrown *reincarnate* and have no access to *resurrection*, should adventurers consider their own dead bodies mildly important. Otherwise, bringing an adventurer back from the dead can get him a new identical body or a random young adult body.

By implication, then, the game *expects* horrible things to happen to adventurers' bodies... then the game expects adventurers to be brought back from the dead in fresh, new bodies. An adventurer doesn't *own* his body; he rents it until a trap or monster decides to evict him. Then *either* somebody finds him a new place to hang his soul for a while until he's kicked out again *or* he goes to his eternal reward because nobody cares about him one way or the other. So it goes.<sup>4</sup>

### Self-mutilation and all that

If a character is unwillingly or inadvertently healed of permanent injuries he'd rather have kept, the GM shouldn't discourage the character from inflicting those injuries again on himself. That's *weird*, but, in a fantasy game that all but requires some classes to change form *somehow* after a certain point *and* expects a soul to be in a new body every so often, not *crazy*.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Other sources of scars include (but aren't limited to) bearing a [*scar of desiny*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/metagame-artifacts/scar-of-destiny), casting the spell [*skinsend*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/skinsend) (which says that scars from the spell "fade normally with the use of healing magic"),<sup>i</sup> an encounter with the haunt [ghostly brands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/haunts/cr-1/ghostly-brands-cr-2), picking the magus arcana [spell-scars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/spell-scars-ex), picking the shaman spirit [battle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/shaman/spirits/battle) and taking hp damage, removing the [*crown of the iron king*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/crown-of-the-iron), and the witch's hex [scar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/common-hexes/hex-scar-su) (a unique case).
<sup>**2**</sup> I, too, thought the various *cure* spells specifically healed damage without scarring, but nothing I've found says that. Just in case I was remembering a different edition, I searched the *Player's Handbooks* and *Dungeon Master's Guides* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition*, and *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons*. Appropriately, only the *Dungeon Master's Guide* for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* mentions scarring:

> If any creature reaches a state of -6 or greater negative hit points before being revived, this could indicate scarring or the loss of some member if you [the Dungeon Master] so choose. (82)

There's your Gygax fix for the day. You're welcome.
<sup>**3**</sup> *Inorganic* replacements include (but aren't limited to) the mundane [hook hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/hook-hand), the magic items [*clockwork arm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/clockwork-arm) and [*clockwork prostheses*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/clockwork-prosthesis), and the implement provided by the trait [Peg Leg](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/skull-shackles/peg-leg). These, too, appear to remain after the creature is the target of the spell *heal* or *greater restoration*; the spell *regenerate*, however, may make it necessary to detach a regenerated part and reattach an inorganic part (certainly a harrowing process!).
<sup>**4**</sup> Some [witches](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/archetypes/paizo---witch-archetypes/beast-bonded) have [*especially* interesting options](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61767/8610).
<sup>**5**</sup> In *View from the Edge* for R. Talsorian Games's role-playing game *Cyberpunk* (1988), after detailing how to improve the Attractiveness attribute, there's this:

> Want to *decrease* your Attractiveness? A straight razor costs fifty-nine cents. (43)

And there's your cyberpunk fix for the day. You're welcome. Again.
<sup>**i**</sup> I plan to work the phrase *normally with the use of magic* into a nongaming conversation at least once today.

Comment: +1, this is my new accepted answer as it includes the philosophical and moral implications too! And a link to another one of my questions.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, **there are no general rules explaining whether or not it's possible to choose whether specific conditions and injuries can be left unaffected by general-purpose curative magic.** It's a bit hard to prove a negative, though.

Given that that's the situation, it's up to the GM to decide how this works. Does the spell's target get a say in which injuries are affected? The spell caster? The deity who grants the caster the spell? Different GMs will rule it different ways.

Oh, and as always, some specific spell descriptions might include this detail. Most don't, though.